# EWS Search Appointments By Required Attendees

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to search appointment by Required Attendees...but below code is not working.
Any idea on how to implement this search. Thanks in advance

```
var Filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or)
        {
            new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees, mailAddress),
            new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees, mailAddress),
        };
            var view = new ItemView(1000)
            {
                PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
            };
FindItemsResults<Item> results = ews.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, Filter, view);
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a supported filter because the Attendees (or really just the recipients) is a collection and SearchFilters can't be used on those type of structures. The closest thing you can do is use AQS and search on the participants

```
string queryString = "Participants:user@domain.com";
FindItemsResults<Item> results = ews.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, queryString, view);
```

That will Participants includes optional attendees but you can just filter the excess appointments you get back at the client side.

Comment: Glen - Thank you. Can we pass multiple participant? For example string querystring = "participant:user1@domain.com or user2@domain.com"

Comment: Yes but you need to qualify the property always so Participants:user@domain.com or Participants:user1@domain.com

Comment: Glen - Thanks so much. Is there a way to include AppointmentStart date comparison. I see "Sent" & "Received" date attributes but i would like to query on AppoitmentStart date

Comment: If you want query a date Range the you shouldn't be using searchfilters or AQS you should use a CalendarView https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx grab all the appointments for that range then filter them at the client side. Using filter won't expand recurring appointments which means you won't capture all the possible appointments in the range.